# SQL Oracle Currency view

Tags: sql, oracle, currency

I would like to know how to change the view symbol for the currency

```
select to_char(fine, 'FM$9999.00')
from fine_table;
```

it shows in USD but i need in Malaysian Ringgits

how to change the currency view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly try the below

```
select TO_char(fine,'FML9999.00',
'NLS_CURRENCY  = RM') from fine_table;
```